# Insert a randomly chosen element of one list in another

Tags: python, list

I have two lists: `list1=["a","b","c","d"]` and `list2=["z","y","x","w"]`.

I would like to take a random element of `list1` and put it at `list2[1]`.

I write `list2.insert(1,random.sample(list1,1))`
but I get `['z',['b'],'y','x','w']`

How do I remove the brackets around the `'b'`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `random.choice`, `random.sample` is for getting a bunch of items:

```
list2.insert(1, random.choice(list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import random
>>> list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> list2 = ["z", "y", "x", "w"]
>>> list2.insert(1, random.sample(list1, 1)[0])
>>> list2
['z', 'b', 'y', 'x', 'w']
```

Just modifying your sample, but indexing the 0th element to remove the braces.

Comment: @Uriel Understood, thank you. English isn't my strongest suit.

Comment: Sure thing. +1 for bothering to correct your post. Keep it on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, assuming you wanted to remove it from list1:

```
list2.insert(1, list1.pop(random.randrange(len(list1)))
```

Comment: Where did you get this assumption from?

Comment: The ambiguity in the original question